# Xfce themes not working when placed in ~/.local/share/themes

Tags: themes, xfce, icon-themes

Might be more of an xfce related problem rather than one in ubuntu. I'm not sure.

To use different theme than greybird in Xubuntu 18.04 i followed these instructions:

https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes

(Points "GTK+ interfaces" and "Windows decorations")

But I noticed that only the system wide installation in

```
/usr/share/themes
/usr/share/icons
```

works.

If I place themes in

```
~/.local/share/themes
```

or

```
~/.icons/
```

respectively, the themes seem to be recocgnized only partially. Some parts of the windows like the close button and some bars appear in the new theme (which is selectable in various customization tools) but most of the windows content (buttons etc.) appear in some Windows-98-like form.

What am I doing wrong?

It isn't that much of a pressing matter since at least the installation in

```
/usr
```

works. But installing it in my home directory seems like the cleaner solution.

Thanks in regards

Markus

Answer (score 1):

Try to put them to

> ~/.themes

When i did , everything worked fine.